# How to convert pretrained fastText vectors to gensim model

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

How to convert pretrained fastText vectors to gensim model?
I need predict_output_word method.

import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec 
from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText

model_wiki = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("wiki.ru.vec")
model3 = Word2Vec(sentences=model_wiki)

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 model3 = Word2Vec(sentences=model_wiki)  # train a model from the corpus
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py
>   in **init**(self, sentences, corpus_file, size, alpha, window,
>   min_count, max_vocab_size, sample, seed, workers, min_alpha, sg, hs,
>   negative, ns_exponent, cbow_mean, hashfxn, iter, null_word, trim_rule,
>   sorted_vocab, batch_words, compute_loss, callbacks, max_final_vocab)
>       765             callbacks=callbacks, batch_words=batch_words, trim_rule=trim_rule, sg=sg, alpha=alpha, window=window,
>       766             seed=seed, hs=hs, negative=negative, cbow_mean=cbow_mean, min_alpha=min_alpha, compute_loss=compute_loss,
>   --> 767             fast_version=FAST_VERSION)
>       768 
>       769     def _do_train_epoch(self, corpus_file, thread_id, offset, cython_vocab, thread_private_mem, cur_epoch,
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py
>   in **init**(self, sentences, corpus_file, workers, vector_size,
>   epochs, callbacks, batch_words, trim_rule, sg, alpha, window, seed,
>   hs, negative, ns_exponent, cbow_mean, min_alpha, compute_loss,
>   fast_version, **kwargs)
>       757                 raise TypeError("You can't pass a generator as the sentences argument. Try an iterator.")
>       758 
>   --> 759             self.build_vocab(sentences=sentences, corpus_file=corpus_file, trim_rule=trim_rule)
>       760             self.train(
>       761                 sentences=sentences, corpus_file=corpus_file, total_examples=self.corpus_count,
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py
>   in build_vocab(self, sentences, corpus_file, update, progress_per,
>   keep_raw_vocab, trim_rule, **kwargs)
>       934         """
>       935         total_words, corpus_count = self.vocabulary.scan_vocab(
>   --> 936             sentences=sentences, corpus_file=corpus_file, progress_per=progress_per, trim_rule=trim_rule)
>       937         self.corpus_count = corpus_count
>       938         self.corpus_total_words = total_words
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py
>   in scan_vocab(self, sentences, corpus_file, progress_per, workers,
>   trim_rule)    1569             sentences = LineSentence(corpus_file)
>   1570 
>   -> 1571         total_words, corpus_count = self._scan_vocab(sentences, progress_per, trim_rule)    1572     1573 
>   logger.info(
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py
>   in _scan_vocab(self, sentences, progress_per, trim_rule)    1538
>   vocab = defaultdict(int)    1539         checked_string_types = 0
>   -> 1540         for sentence_no, sentence in enumerate(sentences):    1541             if not checked_string_types:    1542
>   if isinstance(sentence, string_types):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py
>   in **getitem**(self, entities)
>       337             return self.get_vector(entities)
>       338 
>   --> 339         return vstack([self.get_vector(entity) for entity in entities])
>       340 
>       341     def **contains**(self, entity):
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

According to Gensim docs, you can use [`gensim.models.wrappers`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText.load_fasttext_format) function to:

> Load the input-hidden weight matrix from Facebook’s native fasttext
>   .bin and .vec output files

Here is an example:

```
from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText

model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('wiki.vec')
```

Comment: Thanks! I try it:

Comment: from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText

model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('wiki.ru') 
model.predict_output_word(["car"])

Comment: RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last) .... RuntimeError: Parameters required for predicting the output words not found.